# Calculating Jaccard similarity on two lists to return highest similarity words in Python

Tags: python, similarity, levenshtein-distance, n-gram, sentence-similarity

I have a huge list (containing ~250k words) which was unique words. (Say list1)

I have another list containing 5 words which are misspelled. (Say list2)

I need to find jaccard similarity (based on varying ngrams). between the two lists and return the closest matching word from list1. Working on from a few answers that I found on this site, I was able to:

1. Split both lists into ngrams via a function.
2. Calculate jaccard similarity for first element of the second list and first list.

This is giving me a valid answer. However, I am unable to build on from here to return closest matching words from list1. I know I need to apply the ngram function to each element of my list1. And then compute jaccard similarity with list2 and return the maximum valued element from this. But unable to implement it via a loop. This is the code I'm using:

```
def spell_correcter(list2=['word1', 'word2',... 'word5']):
    from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score
    import re

    def find_ngrams(text: str, number: int=3) -> set:
    #returns a set of ngrams for the given string

        if not text:
            return set()

        str1 = ''.join(text)
        words = [f'  {x} ' for x in re.split(r'\W+', str1.lower()) if x.strip()]

        ngrams = set()

        for word in words:
            for x in range(0, len(word) - number + 1):
                ngrams.add(word[x:x+number])

        return ngrams


    def similarity(text1: str, text2: str, number: int=3) -> float:
    #Finds the similarity between 2 strings using ngrams.

        ngrams1 = find_ngrams(text1, number)
        ngrams2 = find_ngrams(text2, number)
        num_unique = len(ngrams1 | ngrams2)
        num_equal = len(ngrams1 & ngrams2)

        #Tried to compute for entire list1; very slow. Didn't execute
        #for i in range(0, len(text1)):
            #ngrams1 = find_ngrams(text1, number)
            #num_unique = len(ngrams1 | ngrams2)
            #num_equal = len(ngrams1 & ngrams2)
            #jaccard = float(num_equal) / float(num_unique)


        return float(num_equal) / float(num_unique)

    b = list2[0]
    a = similarity(list1, b)

    return a
```

Can someone help with this code?

Answer (score 0):

[Shingling](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/near-duplicates-and-shingling-1.html) is a process of creating a single object by taking consecutive words and grouping them.
We tokenize the list 1 and create a ngram fo len(list2) and calculate the jaccard similarity of each ngram with the list 2. This will give the most similar words in list 1 with words in list 2:

```
def jaccard_similarity(list_x, list_y):
    set_x = set(list_x)
    set_y = set(list_y)
    intersection = set_x.intersection(set_y)
    union = set_x.union(set_y)
    return len(intersection) / len(union) if len(union) > 0 else 0

def shingling_jaccard_similarity(text_x, text_y, n):
    x = list(nltk.ngrams(tokenizer.tokenize(text_x), n))
    y = list(nltk.ngrams(tokenizer.tokenize(text_y), n))
    sim_score = jaccard_similarity(x,y)
    return sim_score

shingling_jaccard_similarity(list1, list2, len(list2))
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation as to why this works?

Comment: In place of `list`, use `set` to make `shingling_jaccard_similarity` more efficient